# Opencv: Get Expectation Maximization (EM) using Gaussian Mixture Model ( GMM)

Tags: c++, opencv, gaussian, mixture-model, expectation-maximization

I am trying to use GMM to find expectation maximization of different colors in a video frame. Then according to that, I will determine which is the dominant color.

For that, my problem is how can I perform GMM based EM to get and compare those expectations for different colors?

Comment: What have you tried? http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/expectation-maximization.html gives an overview on how to use EM from the OpenCV toolkit. Note also that you don't *find* EM, EM is an algorithm to find the maximum likelihood parameters (in your case for a GMM).

Comment: yes, I've read that opencv documentation, and solved this question with the help of another related question. Thank you for your suggestion :)